# How to improve precision of geographic coordinates using ogr2ogr to translate from shapefile to KML?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, kml, ogr2ogr, google-earth

I made a **shapefile** in QGIS (ver 3.16) project with `EPSG:4326`. The shapefile is for a simple polygon and I want to display the polygon on Google Earth so I need to convert it to **KML** format. The [default CRS in Google Earth](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections) is also `EPSG:4326`.

I am using `ogr2ogr` to perform the conversion:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f KML test_polygon.kml test_polygon.shp
```

But visually the position of the KML in Google Earth is offset by about 0.10 second to the west (about 10 feet), and about 0.01 second to the south from the position shown in QGIS. **See images below** (ogr2ogr does not retain styling, so the KML only shows the outline of the shape, but you can still see the position offset).

**Shapefile position shown in QGIS:**
[image]

**KML position shown in Google Earth:**
[image]

Is it possible to improve the precision of the conversion to KML such that the position shown on Google Earth is the same as shown in QGIS? Or perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that the original image is orthorectified with CRS of `WGS84` (`EPSG:4326`)

Comment: The google earth imagery will not be as precise as your orthophoto. It varies across the globe https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306251/are-google-satellite-images-precise-enough-for-georeferencing